# How to add comments to gdb output?

Tags: gdb, comments, ollydbg

When debugging Windows application with Ollydbg, we can add comments to assembly language output as following:

```
00401020   push        ebp    ; add comment here
```

Can we add comments to gdb output just like the way above?

When we input `disassemble` in gdb, it shows like this:

```
(gdb) disassemble main 
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804841d <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x0804841e <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048420 <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x08048423 <+6>: sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x08048426 <+9>: movl   $0x80484d0,(%esp)
   0x0804842d <+16>:    call   0x80482f0 <puts@plt>
   0x08048432 <+21>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x08048437 <+26>:    leave  
   0x08048438 <+27>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Can we add some comments line **0x0804841d** in order that gdb output like this:

```
(gdb) disassemble main 
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804841d <+0>: push   %ebp    ; add comment here
   0x0804841e <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048420 <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x08048423 <+6>: sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x08048426 <+9>: movl   $0x80484d0,(%esp)
   0x0804842d <+16>:    call   0x80482f0 <puts@plt>
   0x08048432 <+21>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x08048437 <+26>:    leave  
   0x08048438 <+27>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we add some comments

No.

Obviously you can save GDB output into a text file and add comments there to your heart's content. But GDB will not display them next time you `disas main`.

Comment: Well, is there any other debuggers that could do the same thing?

Comment: @Bill According to *you*, olliedbg can. I am guessing you want one that works on Linux. I am not aware of any Linux debuggers that support this, and don't really understand why that feature is useful in the first place.

Comment: A bit old but radare2 is able to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, GDB commands can be commented with the **#**.

```
00401020   push        ebp    ; # add comment here
```

http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_16.html

Comment: You're missing what I'm asking about, maybe I need to add some extra details.